# Impossible to make inner object's method private for outside

Tags: scala, private-members

In the following example, I can't get to hide `update` from public exposure:

```
trait Order {
  sealed trait EntryOption {
    private[Order] def update(e: EntryOption): Unit
  }

  private case object EmptyEntry extends EntryOption {
    def update(e: EntryOption) = ()
  }

  trait Entry extends EntryOption

  def test(a: Entry, b: EntryOption): Unit = a.update(b)
}
```

It fails to compile with `"error: object creation impossible, since method $line12$$read$Order$^date in trait EntryOption of type (e: Order.this.EntryOption)Unit is not defined`" – whatever that is supposed to be (compiler bug?). I tried the following without success:

- Also make `update` in `EmptyEntry` `private[Order]`
- Make it `protected` – this breaks method `test`

The goal is to have `EntryOption`'s `update` inaccessible from outside `Order`.

**EDIT**

If I tentatively change `trait Order` to `object Order` it compiles, indicating a potential compiler bug?

Comment: Should update in EntryOption be protected instead of private?

Comment: @david then method `test` cannot access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stupid work-around:

```
trait Order {
  sealed trait EntryOption {
    private[Order] def update(e: EntryOption): Unit
  }

  private sealed trait ScalaChokes extends EntryOption {
    private[Order] final def update(e: EntryOption) = ()
  }

  private case object EmptyEntry extends ScalaChokes

  trait Entry extends EntryOption
}
```

Should I file a bug?